# url rewriting not working automatically

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have problem with url rewriting.

I want to change dynamic link `example.com/new.php?name=latest-news` to `example.com/latest-news-of-the-day`  my .htaccess file configuration is

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule (.*)-of-the-day$ new.php?name=$1[NC,L]
```

Now the page url is still the same, but if I write manually `example.com/latest-news-of-the-day` it works. I want to display new url according to .htaccess file but it is not showing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another rule to externally redirect the browser when they request the `new.php` page:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+new\.php\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1-of-the-day? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *incoming* URI is `/<something>-of-the-day`, and you want to "invisibly" change it to the real file `/new.php?name=<something>`?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(.*)-of-the-day/?$  /new.php?name=$1  [NC,QSA]
```

The [L] flag is unnecessary if there is no RewriteCond, and the [QSA] flag preserves any Query String that came in with the original URI. Note that it does not check if the original URI was an existing directory or file (you can add RewriteCond statements to restrict that).